# Meaning of "consolation" in the following context

Tags: vocabulary

"He took me down, and tied the placard, which was neatly constructed for the purpose, on my shoulders like a knapsack; and wherever I went, afterwards, I had **the consolation** of carrying it.
What I suffered from that placard, nobody can imagine."

(David Copperfield By Charles Dickens)

I understand the general meaning and usage of "consolation", but not in the above example. So I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **sarcastic**, the placard was not a source of **consolation** but the cause of great grief.

A **consolation** prize is given to the person who didn't win just so they don't go away empty handed.

Comment: This is how I read it but still had a little doubt. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a great book

Comment: yes, Peter, and I'm greatly enjoying it.